# PHP : How to get the current value of an array being traversed within an inbuilt function like strpos?

Tags: php, arrays

eg. I want to replace instances of some words with their string length

"XXXX is greater than XX"  becomes  "4 is greater than 2"

Code that I intend to write :

```
$myStrings = Array("XX","XXX","XXXX","XXXXX");
$outStr = str_replace($myStrings,strlen(current($myStrings)),$outStr);
```

But here CURRENT is not working.

P.S. Please do not suggest workarounds to do this stuff since that is not what I intend to ask the forum. My query is getting current pointer to an array being traversed internally.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `array_map`. It applies a function to all elements of an array and outputs the results as a new array:

```
$myStrings = Array("XX","XXX","XXXX","XXXXX");
$outStr = str_replace($myStrings,array_map('strlen', $myStrings)),$outStr);
```

This might create a new problem as XXXX will be replaced with 22 before XXXX is checked. The solution to this would be reverse the input array:

```
$myStrings = array_reverse(Array("XX","XXX","XXXX","XXXXX"));
$outStr = str_replace($myStrings,array_map('strlen', $myStrings)),$outStr);
```

Comment: @Matjis: but will this ensure that strlen is applied to the current needle being checked from $myStrings haystack ?

Comment: @Dhruv: The trick here is that the code creates an array containing the replacement values then does a 1-to-1 replacement from one array to the other.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. Since it's an internal implementation, what would PHP expose to you that you could use to determine the current element?

Note that this is different from accessing internal array pointers using `current()`, `key()`, `next()`, `reset()` et al. I'm referring to the fact that PHP has an internal implementation of `str_replace()` for handling replacements of arrays of strings.

A quick test reveals that PHP doesn't even seem to bother with array pointers when replacing them with `str_replace()` anyway:

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c');             // Internal pointer is at a
$str = 'abc';
next($arr);                              // Internal pointer is at b
echo str_replace($arr, 'x', $str), "\n"; // xxx
echo current($arr), "\n";                // b
```

Oh, by the way, this is what [the manual for `str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) says (strong emphasis mine):

> If *`search`* is an array and *`replace`* is a string, then this replacement string is used for **every value of *`search`***.

So specifically for `str_replace()`, I don't think it was ever intended for you to pass in a replacement string that is dynamic based on the input array.

Comment: Thanks, that was  helpful. I would better write a loop then.

Comment: @Dhruv: You can also use `preg_replace()` to eliminate the need for an array. @mck89 posted an answer for that but deleted it, presumably because you stated not to post workarounds. In any case, be sure to click the checkmark beside an answer to mark it as accepted. Happy hacking!

Answer (score 0):

And http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-walk.php isn´t an option?